# Jar file console window disapears quickly when launched from visual studio

Tags: c#, jar

I am launching a jar file from a C# console application. The problem is, the jar console window disappears too quickly and I don't have time to see the result. I can't seem to find anything on google for this specific case of a C# code running a jar file. All I see is how to make console window not disapear in Visual Studio and it's not what I am looking for.

Here is the C# code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string  path    = "C:\\Example";
     Process process = new Process();
     process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar " + '"' + path + "\\Animal.jar";
     process.Start();

     Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

and the code in the jar file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Animal dog= new Animal();
dog.id=4; dog.name="Jaka";

System.out.println("My dog's name is "+ dog.getName());

}
```

How can I make the jar console window not disappear?

Comment: You need the full path of java.exe in the StartInfo line.  Process does not use the environmental variable PATH so it does not know where to find app.  If you still have issues open a cmd.exe and type line into console window and see what it returns.

Comment: In your Java code, put a line in to read a string from the console.  Even if everything works, that program isn't going to hang around very long.

Comment: It does not make any difference when I provided the full path of java. Also, when I run the jar through cmd line, It runs fine. The problem only appears when I run it through my C# code.

Comment: @Flydog57, thanks. It works.